# lucene ResponseBuilder getFilters wrong encoding for int field type

Tags: solr, lucene

I am getting weird values for solr "int" field type. when listing ResponseBuilder filters i am getting the below value for countryId. Note that outletId field is of type String. this problem is happening with every field in Solr schema with "int" type

[image: term field and its value]

```
<fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>


 List<Query> filters = rb.getFilters();
 Set<Term> curTerms = null;
 for (Query q : filters) {              
  curTerms = new HashSet<Term>();
  q.extractTerms(curTerms);             
  for (Term term : curTerms) {                  
   System.out.println(term.field() + " = " + term.bytes().utf8ToString());
  }
 }
```

Any idea what might be causing this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/4.0.0/org/apache/lucene/index/Term.java#Term.text%28%29

what you got by using term.bytes() is a raw binary representation of the term. If you can convert it to text for string related field, it will never be the case.
To display your term you should first convert it's raw value into an Integer before trying to convert it to a String

you may want to take a look at 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html
for converting a byte[] to an integer

to retrieve the byte array term.bytes().bytes should to the trick.

Also term.bytes().utf8ToString() is equivalent to term.text()